# Relative layout Dependence

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

**Exception raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout**

**Error display**
**Exception raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout**

**Whats i should do to resolve this error i try different ways but not resolve this issue**

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/driverPassengerName1"
            android:layout_width="60px"
            android:layout_height="90px"

            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/driverPassengerName"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/driverRideDetailBtn"
            android:background="@color/second_interaction_eighty_percent_opaque_color"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="Tariq Road Lahore"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="40px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/driverPassengerName"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="90px"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/driverCancelRideBtn"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/driverPassengerName1"
            android:background="@color/second_interaction_eighty_percent_opaque_color"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="2222222222222222222222"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="40px" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/driverCancelRideBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70px"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/decline_color"
            android:padding="5px"
            android:text="@string/cancel_ride"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18px"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/driverRideDetailBtn"
            android:layout_width="60px"
            android:layout_height="60px"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/home"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't understand why you are complicating your implementation. In all of your view you have mentioned `layout_alignParentTop="true"`. Also, I can see you just want to form views in a row. Remove dependencies `toLeftOf` and `toRightOf` from your views and move your view to `LinearLayout`.

Your implementation should be like this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

         <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/driverRideDetailBtn"
            android:layout_width="60px"
            android:layout_height="60px"
            android:background="@drawable/home"
            android:visibility="visible" />

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/driverPassengerName"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="90px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:background="@color/second_interaction_eighty_percent_opaque_color"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="2222222222222222222222"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="40px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/driverPassengerName1"
            android:layout_width="60px"
            android:layout_height="90px"
            android:background="@color/second_interaction_eighty_percent_opaque_color"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="Tariq Road Lahore"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="40px" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/driverCancelRideBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70px"
            android:background="@color/decline_color"
            android:padding="5px"
            android:text="@string/cancel_ride"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18px"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Hope it helps:)

Answer (score 0):

you are telling `RelativeLayout` to keep `driverPassengerName1 TextView` `toLeft` of `driverPassengerName` `TextView` & `driverPassengerName` to keep `rightOf` `driverPassengerName1`! This is of course Circular dependency. Please remove one, either remove

```
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/driverPassengerName"
```

From First TextView

or

```
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/driverPassengerName1"
```

from Second TextView